Would asking if non‐moving animals (like oysters) are included in Bereshit 9:3 be a duplicate?
I want to determine the extent of what Bereshit 9:3 means in allowing Noah to eat “every moving thing that lives,” particularly the “moving” part. Would a living animal that does not move, such as an (e.g., cooked) oyster, fall outside the scope of Bereshit 9:3?
However, some already‐existent questions come close to asking whether the “moving” part of Bereshit 9:3’s wording excludes non‐moving animals:

Remes - רֶמֶשׂ - in Genesis 9:3
Genesis Chapter 9 : 3 Meaning
Can a Ben-Noach eat live oysters?

However, none of these questions deal squarely with whether Bereshit 9:3’s wording excludes non‐moving animals—though the first question in the list above comes close. Should I:

Create a new question asking whether non‐moving animals falls outside the scope of Bereshit 9:3’s broad wording; or
Modify the first question in the list above to explicitly ask whether Bereshit 9:3’s wording excludes non‐moving animals, such as oysters?


Your question wouldn't be a duplicate of any of the others.

The first question asks about different meanings of the word "moving thing," not about whether non-moving animals are included.
The second asks to explain a contradiction in the verse (unclear exactly what, but in any event doesn't ask whether non-moving animals are considered a "moving thing").
The third asks whether a Ben Noach can eat live oysters (assuming, not asking, that oysters are permissible), and doesn't ask about any distinction between moving and non-moving animals.
The two questions which marked as duplicates of the third ask either about live fish, considered from the perspective of the prohibition of a limb taken from a live animal (a totally different issue), or how a Ben Noach can practically know what meat is permissible, not about a distinction between moving and non-moving animals.

So to answer the questions:

None of the other questions ask your question about a distinction between moving and non-moving animals. So if you want to ask about it, you should create a new question (you might want to mention in the question itself that the other questions are not the same as yours, to preempt mistaken duplicate votes).

In case of ambiguity, I think you shouldn't edit someone's ambiguous question to make it address yours (absent some critical problem). Instead, you should ask a new unambiguous question and leave the ambiguous one as it is. (But in this case, the first question isn't ambiguous anyway. It's asking unambiguously why the word רמש is translated as "moving thing" in Genesis 9:3 and not "creeping thing" as it's translated everywhere else, which is a completely different question.)



Thanks, I love your breakdown on why my question isn’t a duplicate of the others. I’ll include the useful info you put in my question. Perfect!

It's preferable you don't change the intent of someone else's question. I don't know enough about the issue you're asking about, so I'm not sure about the first option. But a third, more viable option is to consider placing a bounty on the older question stating you're specifically looking for an answer that addresses your own issue.
